# Where is FIMSplash.htm page for forefront identity manager 2012?

Tags: security, identity

I am installing FIM 2012, I did following steps.
1 Installed sql instance.
2 Installed share point instance.
3 Configured  SharePoint Foundation 2013 for FIM 2012 SP1 Portal

in the last step I am not able to get Fimsplash.htm which I see when I installing FIM 2010

I'm refereeing following link.
http://www.fimspecialist.com/fim-portal/installing-fim-2010-r2-sp1-portal-on-sharepoint-foundation-2013/